# Trouble getting my html tags to show up inside my div border

Tags: html, css

I am new to this, so the page is for practice. I can't seem to get the "p" or "h1" tags to show up in, what should be the middle of my page. Here is my html code:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="top">
  <div id="bottom">
    <div id="left">
      <div id="right">
      </div>
      <!--Attempted to use a p tag here -->
    <!--right div end-->
  </div>
  <!--left div end-->
</div>
<!--bottom div end-->
</div>
<!--top div end-->
</div>
<!--container div end-->
<!--Attempted to use a p tag here as well thinking it may show up in a different location-->
</body>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
#top,
#bottom,
#left,
#right {
background: #666666;
position: fixed;
}

#left,
#right {
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100px;
}

#left {
left: 0;
}

#right {
right: 0;
}

#top,
#bottom {
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100px;
}

#top {
top: 0;
}

#bottom {
bottom: 0;
}
```

If anyone could let me know what I am doing wrong it would be very appreciated. I tried to mess with the positioning a bit with no luck, and I also attempted to give the p tags a z-index but I don't know if that was even something that could have worked properly to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

A trick to center elements in the middle is:

```
#left{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

but if you're just looking to center the `<h1>` or `<p>` then this would work:

```
p {
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly acceptable and simpler way to achieve what you want.

```css
body {
  background-color: #666666;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>HEADER 1</h1>
    <p>PARAGRAPH 1</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with float and clear in the css segments

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper{background-color:red;width:100%; margin: auto;}
#top{background-color:blue;  height:100px;}
#left{background-color:green;   width:10%; height:100px;float:left;}
#right{background-color:yellow;  width: 10%; height:100px;float:right;}
#bottom{background-color:grey; height:100px;clear:left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="top">top</div>
<div id="left">left</div>background
<div id="right">right</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you! It looks like my whole setup was completely wrong :(

Comment: Maybe a little bit, but the attempt was really good for the beginning. Look out for w3schools.com you can find a lot of help on that site, too.